# I need a help - Making this bad query better

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, max

```
Select
Max(isnull(UpdateDate, InsertDate)) as A
From yourTable
Where UpdateCode = 'ABC' or InsertCode = 'ABC'

Select
Max(isnull(UpdateDate, InsertDate)) as B
From yourTable
Where UpdateCode = 'ZYX' or InsertCode = 'ZYX'
```

I want to this two query in one query.
So I made it like this

```
Select
Max(isnull(UpdateDate, InsertDate)) as A,
Max(isnull(UpdateDate, InsertDate)) as B
From yourTable
Where (UpdateCode = 'ZYX' or InsertCode = 'ZYX')
or (UpdateCode = 'ABC' or InsertCode = 'ABC')
```

This query brings wrong data.

Comment: Sample data and expected results are probably going to help here. Also, "help me?" isn't a question on it's own. Please ask a **specific** question. What do you need *help* with? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query `A`and `B` are the exact same term, so they'll have the exact same value. 
One way to handle this is to add the logic in a `case` expression in the `max` calls:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN 'ABC' IN (InsertCode, UpdateCode) 
                THEN ISNULL(UpdateDate, InsertDate)
           END) AS a
       MAX(CASE WHEN 'XYZ' IN (InsertCode, UpdateCode) 
                THEN ISNULL(UpdateDate, InsertDate)
           END) AS a
FROM  YourTable
-- Where clause is an optimization, functionality would be correct even without it
WHERE 'ABC' IN (InsertCode, UpdateCode) OR
      'XYZ' IN (InsertCode, UpdateCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to conditionally calculate each `MAX`.

```
Select
    Max(CASE WHEN UpdateCode = 'ZYX' or InsertCode = 'ZYX' THEN isnull(UpdateDate, InsertDate) END) as A,
    Max(CASE WHEN UpdateCode = 'ABC' or InsertCode = 'ABC' THEN isnull(UpdateDate, InsertDate) END) as B
From 
    yourTable
Where   
    UpdateCode IN ('ZYX', 'ABC') or InsertCode IN ('ZYX', 'ABC')
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way is to combine two Statements with "Union select".

Otherwise you have to clearly describe your expectations to the result.

Answer (score 0):

The query itself seems a little bizarre but I believe you have 2 choices;

First is to use an "IN" statement to allow your where conditions to be able to meet multiple criteria

i.e

```
WHERE UpdateCode IN (‘ABC’, 'ZYX') or InsertCode IN (‘ABC’, 'ZYX')
```

Second is to use a JOIN to get both fields to match - I think this is more towards what you're aiming for

```
SELECT 
    ds1.A
    ds2.B
FROM (
    Select
        1 AS ID,
        Max(isnull(UpdateDate, InsertDate)) as A        
    From yourTable
    Where UpdateCode = 'ABC' or InsertCode = 'ABC'
) ds1
INNER JOIN (
    Select
        1 AS ID,
        Max(isnull(UpdateDate, InsertDate)) as B
    From yourTable
    Where UpdateCode = 'ZYX' or InsertCode = 'ZYX'
) ds2
ON ds1.ID = ds2.ID
```